# Unused variable was not declared. gcc teasing me?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, compiler-errors

I have next lines in my code:

```
const int xxx = hhh.IR(); // line 234
if( !aaaaaaa[iT][xxx] ) // line 235
```

the compiler complains:

```
/FILE.cxx:234:21: warning: unused variable 'xxx' [-Wunused-variable]
/FILE.cxx:235:30: error: 'xxx' was not declared in this scope
```

(Is it teasing me?) How is this even possible?

I checked that both `xxx` use same characters, simply coping one `xxx` and replacing other one by it.

P.S.:
I have

- gcc 4.7.3
- OSX 10.9.

Comment: Nice variables' names, by the way.

Comment: @KirilKirov, nice file name too ;)

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  I suspect a mystery macro expansion.  Try running your code through `g++ -E` and see what those lines expand to.

Comment: What's the type of `aaaaaaa`?

Comment: This could be a compiler bug.  You should simplify your code as much as possible and post the whole thing, including the exact command used to invoke the compiler.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you prepared a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I wonder, why 3 people vote close because the question is not about programming...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible when scope of first and second lines are different.

Here an example of code which will give such errors:

```
if ( y == z )
  const int xxx = hhh.IR();
  if( !aaaaaaa[iT][xxx] )
```

which is equal to:

```
if ( y == z ) {
  const int xxx = hhh.IR();
}
if( !aaaaaaa[iT][xxx] )
```

So fix was to add braces:

```
if ( y == z ) {
  const int xxx = hhh.IR();
  if( !aaaaaaa[iT][xxx] )
```

Comment: Probably the most likely explanation.

Comment: They're called "braces".